# не работает background-image. путь к файлу указан верно

Tags: html, css, изображения

Вот пример кода.

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


.header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url("images/Logo-Blog_76.png");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my.css">
  <title>mysite</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: проверьте путь к изображению

Comment: много раз проверял)

Comment: ошибок в консоле нет ?

Comment: попробуйте данный вариант - background-image: url("../images/Logo-Blog_76.png");

Comment: нету. css работает т.е. link правильный не пойму в чем проблема

Comment: Да и я бы проверил заглавные буквы, ели сервер не windows это бывает критично. Еще можно скопировать пусть и добавить в строку запроса, покажет или нет фото.

Comment: Можно проверить инлайново    <div class="header" style="background-image: url('images/Logo-Blog_76.png')">
</div>

Comment: @ArtashesMuradyan а в консоле у Вас должна была быть ошибка, т.к. путь до файла был неправильный и файл не загрузился

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример вашего кода и все здесь работает. Я изменил картинку на любую и дал абсолютный `url` что бы и здесь было видно.

Для того что бы проверить задайте путь картинки абсолютным. И увидите что вы путь задаете не так как надо.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-image: url("https://servicedesk.dc-uoit.ca/Slides/IT%20Image%203.jpg");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my.css">
    <title>mysite</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: обычно такие вопросы закрываются по причине "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой"

Comment: @Alex Тогда как человек должен задать подобный вопрос? Может поможете ему сформулировать вопрос правильно?

Comment: а такой вопрос уже был (см. причину закрытия)

Comment: @Alex А вы другое говорили

Comment: отвечая на Ваш вопрос, если не закрывать такой вопрос, то можно улучшить заголовок изменив его на "почему не работает ... ?" На самом деле решением этого и подобных вопросов является F12 в любом браузере, поэтому вопрос можно было бы и закрыть. С другой стороны если вопрос уникальный и есть решение в ответе, то лучше улучшить вопрос и оставить открытым, чтобы в дальнейшем закрывать подобные вопросы как дубликаты. Поэтому "обычно закрываются" вместо "стоит закрыть".

Answer (score 0):

Путь до изображения считается относительно файла стилей, а они у вас в разных папках. Должно быть

```
../images/Logo-Blog_76.png
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Получилось)